# How to remove Swipe Effect using CSS?

Tags: css, wordpress, templates, animation, effect

I'm trying to customise a Wordpress Template and I need to force a few effects using CSS.

Here's the url : http://jeanmarcmouchet.fr/gallery/gallery-name/tm_pg_album/hotel-particulier-geneve/

I don't want the Swipe Effect when hovering the pictures but I can't find the proper CSS rule responsible for this. Could it be generated in jQuery ?

If you guys could check the code and tell me what I missed you'd help me a lot. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has transition and other styles on the following selector

```
.tm-pg_front_gallery .tm-pg_front_gallery-masonry .tm_pg_gallery-item_link img {
        transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
        opacity: 1;
}

.tm-pg_front_gallery .tm-pg_front_gallery-masonry .tm_pg_gallery-item_link:hover img {
        transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
        opacity: 1;
}
```

Comment: THanks for your help. It seems that's the right class but the Swipe doesn't stop with those rules :
.tm-pg_front_gallery .tm-pg_front_gallery-masonry .tm_pg_gallery-item_link:hover img {
 transition:none !important;
 transform:none !important;
}

Comment: Did the answer help ?

Comment: No, there's still the Swipe effect even though there's no transition anymore.
Check the website, I updated it.

Comment: Sorry but this doesn't work either :( Could it be a Javascript effect ?

Comment: No its not. Cause when i remove 'tm_pg_gallery-item_link' class from anchor, I can no longer see the transition. Can you remove this class from the anchors containing images ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171321/discussion-between-nandita-arora-sharma-and-gregory-santana).

Comment: The issue is that by default the value of transform was set to translate3d(-40px, 0, 0) and we it was being changed to translate3d(0, 0, 0) on hover. I didnt realise this yesterday. You just need to apply the same styles on both hover and default states.

Comment: Yes ! It works with both states set by default !
Thanks for your help, it was driving me crazy !